# I have created an element in plain css by a bookmarklet. It is created, but not visible

Tags: javascript, html, css, user-interface

My code follows:

```
g = document.createElement('div');
g.setAttribute("id", "divcontainer");

g.innerHTML = `

HTML GOES HERE

`
```

When I use this on a site, I want the div centered and visible, it is working in the fact that it creates the div (tested that in console) but I cannot see it.

I am not using JQuery but if I need to, I can. My goal is to have a UI type thing.

Comment: _"I have created an element in plain css..."_ - No. CSS cannot create elements...

Comment: `.createElement()` creates an element but doesn't add it to the DOM -> `.appendChild()` / `.insertAdjacentElement()`

Comment: You need to also add inline CSS to the JS code you already have.

Answer (score 0):

Your code only creates the element but doesn't add it to the DOM, in order to do that you have to use `document.body.appendChild(element)` and that will add the element to the body element, you can also use the same method to add the element inside and element that you select by id or by QuerySelector.

You can modify your code as follows :

```
g = document.createElement('div');
g.setAttribute("id", "divcontainer");

g.innerHTML = `HTML GOES HERE`;
document.body.appendChild(g);
```

If you want to add multiple elements you can use `append()` instead of `appendChild()`.

`document.body.append(g,g2,g3,g4)`

Hope that helps!